# How do steps and Pokémon Gen VI O-Powers relate?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I heard that the number of steps you have collected in a given day affects the speed of O-Power green light ball thingies (what you need to use O-powers) regen rate. How does this work?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Bulbapedia entry on O-Powers](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/O-Power#O-Power_energy):

- **0-2000 steps:** 1× energy regeneration rate
- **2001-3000 steps:** 2× energy regeneration rate
- **3001-2000 steps:** 3× energy regeneration rate
- **4001+ steps:** 4× energy regeneration rate

The base rate for O-Power energy regeneration is 1 circle every 4 minutes. At the maximum regeneration rate, this becomes one circle every minute. As the 3ds's step counter resets at midnight (based on the system clock), so to does your O-Power regeneration rate return to 1x at midnight each day.

Comment: woah! thats alot of steps! and i found out the circles are called energy

Comment: Does the level of the O-power affect the number of steps you need?

Comment: @TheMagicKittten No, your energy is global; all O-Powers draw from the same pool of energy that replenishes at the rate described in my answer. Higher level O-Powers require more energy per activation, so having a higher regeneration rate is more desirable in order to activate the powers more often, but is not required.

Comment: yay i have 2000 steps

Comment: so 1x is 4 min per circle, 2x is 3 min, 3x is 2 min, and 4x is 1 min?

Comment: 1x is base speed, 4 min. 2x is twice the speed, or 2 min. 3x is three times the speed, or roughly 1 min 20 seconds. 4x is four times the speed, or 1 min.

Comment: oh and btw i have a 2DS not a 3DS